Ratchet PHP with SSL : Apache's Proxy is not working
I'm having issues with Ratchet on a SSL URL.
Here is my configuration:
I have Apache 2.4 and the last PHP Ratchet (2.4.4)
My Chat's script (from the Ratchet official tutorial) is perfectly is working in localhost (using telnet)
But as soon as I use it from a web browser it's not working: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://ws.my_site.fr/wss2/' failed: "
I read here that I needed to use a proxy. I thought I did it right, so I'm not sure what's wrong :
My configuration file (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-my_site-ssl.conf) :
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost my_site.fr:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://ws.my_site.fr:8080/

    ServerName my_site.fr

My js file: (which returns "websocket connection failed on ...")
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://ws.my_site.fr/wss2/');

conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};

And finally the server's script (which work in localhost!):
<?php
    use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
    use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
    use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
    use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();

Thanks for your help!
